# Mounted point for a RAID drive not available when logging in via SSH

Tags: ssh, mount, mdadm

In my machine, I mounted a mdadm RAID array using `sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid`. Mounting is successful and I able to access the drive. RAID assembly is also successful and has a clean state.

I used to be able to ssh into my machine and also have access to `/mnt/raid`, however after an update, the mounted point is not showing up when logging in via SSH. How could I troubleshoot this and restore access to `/mnt/raid` when I ssh into my machine?

This is the output when I am directly logged into my machine

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda       8:0    0  256G  0 disk
sdb       8:16   0  256G  0 disk  /
sdc       8:32   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid
sdd       8:48   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sdd1    8:49   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid
sde       8:64   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sde1    8:65   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid
sdf       8:80   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sdf1    8:81   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid

$ df -hT | grep /dev/md0
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0       ext4    49T   40T  7.0T  86% /mnt/raid

$ mount | grep /dev/md0
/dev/md0 on /mnt/raid type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=256)
```

and this is what I see when I log in via ssh: (`/dev/md0` does not show as mounted)

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda       8:0    0  256G  0 disk
sdb       8:16   0  256G  0 disk  /
sdc       8:32   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5
sdd       8:48   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sdd1    8:49   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5
sde       8:64   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sde1    8:65   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5
sdf       8:80   0 16.4T  0 disk
└─sdf1    8:81   0 16.4T  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0 49.1T  0 raid5

$ df -hT | grep /dev/md0
$ mount | grep /dev/md0
$
```